# Need help matching a pattern using egrep in bash scripting [ SED/GREP]

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

So I need to match a string in given word list.
For example, if I give the input like

```
$ sh match_the_pattern.sh -i aei words.txt
```

It should match the character "a" "e" and "i" in order.

**the alphabets in the string must occur in the word in that order, but that other characters may occur in between.**

Note : the character string may change and the dictionary may change.

My Approach :

1. Read the input
2. Scan for the filename
3. SED or GREP combination to match the character string
4. Output

What I do not know? the 3rd part.

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  case $1 in
       -i)
    arg=$2
    egrep "*[$argument]*" $name
    shift ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

### What did not work

```
a+.*e+.*i+.*

sh match_the_pattern.sh -i aeiou words.txt

adventitious
adventitiousness
sacrilegious
abstemious
sacrilegiousness
```

if you notice, a,e,i,o,u are in order one after another. That is what I want.
the character string which we are going to match may change.

Comment: `grep 'a.*e.*i'`?

Comment: `egrep "a+.*e+.*i+.*" words.txt` does match these words. What did you find to be the problem?

Comment: The reason being, you are just taking aei and matching it. I have clearly mentioned that aei is just a sample, it is a variable which changes with the argument. It could be xyz,abc, euo, or anything. So our grep should not be hardly coded. It must be have parameters or something which is variable. I hope this helps.

Comment: Is the question basically "how do I turn a string into the same string with `.*` inserted between each character"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$argument` should contain only letters; generate the pattern using sed, match words using grep:

```
grep "$(sed 's/./&.*/g' <<< "$argument")" "$name"
```